# JAVA Display how many ODD and EVEN numbers using only one counter?

Tags: java

I have a program here in java that asks the user to input ten integer numbers and would print out how many are ODD and how many are EVEN.

```
import java.io.*;
public class Count {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int i, , even_ctr=0, odd_ctr = 0;
        String input = " ";

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader ( new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        for(i = 1; i <=10; i++){
            try{
            System.out.print("Input integer number: ");
                input = in.readLine();
               }catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println("Error!");
               }

               n = Integer.parseInt(input);

               if(n % 2 == 0)
                even_ctr++;      //counter for even
               if(n % 2 == 0)
                odd_ctr++;      //counter for odd
        }System.out.println("EVEN: " + even_ctr + "\nODD: "+ odd_ctr);
    }
}
```

I am trying to change the program by using only one counter instead of two counter. Anyone knows how?

Comment: Keep track of odd, even is 10-odd?

Comment: Also your code increments both counters only for even integers.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
public class NewClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int i,n,  even_ctr=0;
        String input = " ";

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader ( new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        for(i = 1; i <=10; i++){
            try{
            System.out.print("Input integer number: ");
                input = in.readLine();
               }catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println("Error!");
               }

               n = Integer.parseInt(input);

               if(n % 2 == 0)
                even_ctr++;      

        }System.out.println("EVEN: " + even_ctr + "\nODD: "+ (10-even_ctr));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just keep the first counter incrementing for ODD number detection (OR EVEN but either of them). At the end of the computation, if ODD counter = 4, and total number of numbers entered are 10, then 10 - ODDcounter = 10 - 4 = 6 are the number of even numbers.

Answer (score 0):

For this it looks like it would be equally useful to use the Scanner so that you can avoid the step of having to parse the string.This also would require you to    `import java.util.Scanner` but you can use the scanner to take in strings or integers.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int input;
int evenCount = 0;

 for(i = 1; i <=10; i++){
        try{
        System.out.print("Input integer number: ");
            input = in.nextInt();
           }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Error!");
           }

           if(input % 2 == 0)
              evenCount++;
    }
System.out.println("EVEN: " + evenCounter + "\nODD: "+ (10 - evenCounter);
```

Include `in.close();` at the end of the method to close the scanner or the reader which ever you use.

Answer (score 0):

```
package evenoddten;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class EvenOddTen {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int num1 = 0, num2, even = 0, count = 0;
        Scanner scr = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Total Nos:");
        num2 = scr.nextInt();

        while(count<num2) {
            System.out.println("Enter no:");
            num1 = scr.nextInt();
            if (num1%2 == 0) {
                even = even + 1;
            }           
            count = count+1;
        }
        System.out.println("Even nos are:"+even);
        System.out.println("Odd nos are:"+(count - even));
    }  
}
```

Comment: There is a useless for loop. Pls, check.

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged, please help the user by explaining what your code is doing, and pointing out the flaws in his program. As a side comment, our code has an empty for loop, why did you still keep it? The question asks to use only one counter, you didn't change this in your code either